# Read data from huge mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, cursor

I have a mongo collection of documents 1000_000_000 and want to read them with some kind of recovery mechanism.
I have used a cursor for partial data processing, and wondering to know: is there any way in case of my client is disconnected from db, to start reading from the last position, and not from the beginning?

Comment: If you don't mind altering existing data, you can simply add a flag `processed: true` to indicate the record is processed after you did so. You can select `processed: {$exists: false}` when reading the data.

Comment: Data is immutable)